# How did Torreto lose his cross from his neck in Fast Five?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-and-furious-franchise, fast-five

I've recently been watching *The Fast And The Furious* movie series with my fiancee, that when I noticed a flaw or I may have missed something.

In the movie *Fast Five* - 2011, the scene where Dom first met Officer Neves and rescued her from the shooting saying: "They already know who you are". We can see the cross on his neck (Minute 33:09):

[image: Torreto still ha2 his cross]

A minute later, after agent Hobbs passes by Neves, she sees the cross on the ground (Minute 34:43):

[image: Cross on floor]

How did Torreto actually lose the cross? Was that a flaw from the director, or something that I've missed?

Comment: It's most likely just a [continuity error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_editing#Continuity_editing_and_alternatives). The scenes, although they seem contiguous⁯, may have been shot on different days (or at least hours), so details such as those are hard to keep track of. I've personally seen errors like these zillions of times.

Comment: Nope...not an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Basically...it just fell off (as strange as that may sound).

It's covered in the [**script**](http://freepdfhosting.com/7e76c77130.pdf)

> ```
>  Elena nods and he (Hobbs) moves off, continuing the hunt for Toretto.
>  When he's gone she NOTICES something shining in the dirt. 
>  Moving closer, we see it's LETTY's NECKLACE. 
>  It must have fallen off Dom when he saved her life
> ```

We know that Dom didn't deliberately drop it since he's surprised to see Elena wearing the necklace later and he then proceeds to break into her home to get it back.

Essentially, it's a *plot device* to bring these two characters together.

Comment: Well, for sure it didn't fell off him when he saved her, because the first image in the question is right after he saved her => continuity error. Good answer nevertheless. It shows what was intended.

Comment: I guess you're both are right, I was certain it should be in the script, but wanted to know if there's some kind of error in the shooting, or there's something else that I didn't really see. Thanks.